# Android Position Custom Toast Above User's touch

Tags: android, positioning, toast

I have created a custom background for a Toast message. I use the MotionEvent to grab the rawX and rawY then show the Toast where the user tapped. The only issue is that the top of the Toast appears below the users touch point and not above it. So basically if I knew the height of the Toast when I show it I could move it up the Y axis that much so it would be above the users tap x,y point. However, you can't get the height of the Toast before it is drawn. Else is there another way to achieve the right position with the Gravity parameters?

```
        //Retrieve the layout inflator
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //Assign the custom layout to view
        //Parameter 1 - Custom layout XML
        //Parameter 2 - Custom layout ID present in linearlayout tag of XML
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_toast,
                    (ViewGroup) llayParent.findViewById(R.id.popToastLayoutRoot));


        m_tv_what = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.ptextWhat);
        m_tv_priority = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.ptextPrior);
        m_tv_where  = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.ptextWhere);
        m_tv_notes = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.ptextNotes);

        m_tv_what.setText(row.sSubject);
         switch((int)row.lPriority){
            case 3:
                m_tv_priority.setText("low");
            break;

            case 2:
                m_tv_priority.setText("medium");
            break;

            case 1:
                m_tv_priority.setText("HIGH");
            break;

         }
         m_tv_where.setText(row.sWhere);
         m_tv_notes.setText(row.sDescription);



        //Return the application context
        Toast toast = new Toast(ctx);
        //Set toast gravity to bottom

             //the height is 0 of course , because it has not been drawn yet
             //any way to get height?
            int height =layout.getHeight();

             toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT ,(int)x, (int)y );
        //Set toast duration
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //Set the custom layout to Toast
        toast.setView(layout);
        //Display toast
        toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a toast, I ended up using an Activity with a transparent background. The content view (RelativeLayout) of the activity contains the same view I had set for the toast.  I then set the  RelativeLayout's padding_top dynamically so pushes it down so the bottom of the RelativeLayout it right where the user touched.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the setGravity() method, first get the coordinates of user touch and then try something like this:

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, x, y);
```

where x and y are offsets in x and y coordinates starting from the top-left corner and Gravity is a constant.

Comment: I'm already using SetGravity() see my code...but its positioning it below the users tap point and I want to position it above the user's tap point, in other words the bottom of the toast is right at the y pos of the user's tap

Comment: Well just modify the offset, thats exactly what it is for

Comment: That's the issue, I don't know how much to offset y, it cannot be a static value because of different screen resolutions -- therefore it must be dynamic and what I need is the height of the toast at the time I show it and I don't know how to get that.